# Finding the most frequently occurring combination

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image][image]I have two table with name Orders and Products,The order table contains the number of specific orders made by a customer and the products included in that order is in the Products table.

My requirement is to get the number of total orders against the most frequently coming products.
means for these products  product 1,Product 2, product 3 what is the total orders,If an order contains 10 Products which contains Product 1 ,Product 2 and Product 3 that order should be counted.

For an order_id there can be multiple products will be there and i'm confused on how to get this result.Can anyone share or suggest a solution on how to get this?

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Below is the sample query ,

```
SELECT 
    "Orders"."order_id",pr.product_name
FROM 
    "data"."orders" AS "Orders"
    LEFT JOIN  data.items i On i."order_id"="Orders"."order_id" 
    LEFT join  data.products pr on pr."product_id"=i."product_id" 
WHERE TO_CHAR("Orders"."created_at_order",'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-04-30'
ORDER BY  "Orders"."order_id"
```

[image]

Desired Result will be like this(3 columns),The most purchased product combination with number of occurring orders.

Product 1,  Product 2,Product 3,etc..... , Number Of Orders

This is the sample data output,Need the product list which is purchased in combination the most.(As of now i have given only 3 columns for sample but it may vary according to the number of PRODUCTS in an order).

and example

Comment: Sample data and desired results  would help.  In addition, your text says "two tables" but your code references three tables.  Very confusing.

Comment: Hi gordon, Thanks a lot for the prompt reply! the third table items is not that important in this case as it is used to link the other two tables.The data which i want to display is the first two tables.I'll update the sample data and desired results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    "Orders"."order_id",
    string_agg(DISTINCT pr.product_name,::character varying, ',') AS product_name
    count(1) AS product_no
FROM 
    "data"."orders" AS "Orders"
    LEFT JOIN  data.items i On i."order_id"="Orders"."order_id" 
    LEFT join  data.products pr on pr."product_id"=i."product_id" 
WHERE TO_CHAR("Orders"."created_at_order",'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-04-30'
GROUP BY "Orders"."order_id"
ORDER BY  count(1);
```

You can try to use group by clause.

Comment: But i need the combination of products,which combination have the customers purchased the most.This is not what i need.

Comment: Checking on it @Rahul Singh

Comment: @SandeepSalim What is the data type of orderid

Comment: Order_id is BIGINT,Since i got the below error while executing the code.ERROR:  function string_agg(text) does not exist, i used array_agg instead of string_agg casting order id to text

Comment: @SandeepSalim both the function are more or less the same. With a small difference. I have made the changes to the query. Please check if it's working.

Comment: Hi Rahul,The query is giving me the orders which a particular product is there.But i want the product combination which is purchased the most.Means in an order id if there is 3 products ,i want the combination of those products along with its orders in which these combination have occurred.

Comment: @SandeepSalim Can you please add a sample set for desired result

Comment: Hi Rahul,Have added an sample output image above,please check.

Comment: ,Any idea on how to get like this,It will be very much helpful.

Comment: @SandeepSalim I have made the new changes. Also it will be excellent if you share the table structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193694/discussion-between-rahul-singh-and-sandeep-salim).

Comment: Hi Rahul,Ordrs table-> Order_id as PK, and other order related columns which is not relevant in this  and Items  table is the linking table for orders and Products table which contains item_id,order_id and,product_id(multiple entries) and products table contains product_id and Product_name(multiple possible).For each order there are multiple entries in the orders and items table based on the number of items in an order.

Comment: Rahul tried your solution,i'm getting the product names against each order separated by comma but the product names are duplicated in it.Same name is occuring multiple times.

Comment: Changes made to the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahul for the support,it didn't exactly gave what i want,but this solution is also good.Also do you know any idea on how to check a particular comma separated string is included in another comma separated string. Like i have product_ids '4444,1567,3567'  and the appended product combinations will be many for example '4444,6789,0098,1567,3567',Is it possible to check whether the  above string (all elements) is included in another comma separated list.

Comment: Let continue in chat

Comment: Sure,If you have a solution for this then it will totally solve the isue im facing right now.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193694/discussion-between-rahul-singh-and-sandeep-salim Lets join

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generally get the number of orders against some products then you can just count the number of orders grouped on the products from product table. Query should look something like this:

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) 
FROM data.products
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
LIMIT 1;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use GROUP BY and take MOST counted value as below-

```
SELECT 
pr.product_name,
COUNT(DISTINCT Orders.order_id)
FROM 
"data"."orders" AS "Orders"
LEFT JOIN  data.items i On i."order_id"="Orders"."order_id" 
LEFT join  data.products pr on pr."product_id"=i."product_id" 
WHERE TO_CHAR("Orders"."created_at_order",'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-04-30'
GROUP BY pr.product_name
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT Orders.order_id) DESC
LIMIT 1 -- You can use the LIMIT or NOT as per requirement
```

Comment: Checked this,It is only giving the total count of each products against order_id,but i need the combination of products which has been purchased the most.

Comment: Means which is the most purchased product combination and its number odforders.is there a way to get it?

Comment: The query should returned the combination of order_id/product_name that available for Maximum time.

Comment: Hi,The requirement is to get the product combinations and its number of orders.Suppose if in one order there are three products i want to get the number of orders in which those three products are included.Note that in an order there might be many products .

Comment: So you want the order_id where most number of product included?

Comment: I want the combination of products means product names which occurred in most orders and the count of that orders.

Comment: Updated. Can you check this meet your requirement or not?

Comment: Sure,Checking on it.

Comment: I think now I got your point. I can see there are 5 product against Order ID 435358 and you want 5 column for that order id right? And also that number of product is Dynamic... right?

Comment: hi Rabbani,yes indeed,that is what i want .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193696/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-sandeep-salim).

Comment: No,its only showing the product name with the occured order count,I want the combination of products having maximum orders,Hope i have made it clear :(